# Will there be a web-based Daedalus wallet?

Tags: wallet

Will there be a web version of the official Daedalus wallet? It is possible to build one for the Cardano community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Daedalus is a full-node wallet, which means it runs `cardano-node` (no web version) and downloads a copy of the blockchain onto your computer. With a blockchain size of 10GB and growing, it doesn't really make sense for Daedalus to run in a full web browser.

Yoroi is the official web/light wallet, available as a chrome extension, iOS, or Android app. https://yoroi-wallet.com/